# Why did Growl stop working with Adium after I installed Google notifier?

Tags: macos, mac, troubleshooting, adium, growl

Once I installed Gmail notifier, Growl stopped working with Adium.  I don't know if it switched it off somewhere, or what.  Either way, I've since uninstalled Gmail notifier and still no dice on Growl with Adium.

What gives?

*edit*:  I've tried installing over growl.  No dice.

Comment: did you try removing all preferences and preference panes, then reinstalling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall [growl](http://growl.info/).

if that doesn't work, check out the preferences pane. Delete it. Delete all of your preferences. Then Reinstall growl again.

Comment: I can't find growl under applications or utilities.  Where can I find it to delete it?

Comment: Growl is a preference pane, so it'll be under `/Library/PreferencePanes` or `~/Library/PreferencePanes`.